# Force Visual Studio to Decorate Function Name in a Particular Way

Tags: visual-studio, function

thank you for your time.

The company I work for has a program, originally written in 1998, which does some work on a specialty system.  We wrote the DLL files in house that provide the API that the program uses to interface with the system.  The Windows user interface was farmed out to another company back in 1998.  It was originally written for Windows 98 but we are still using it succesfully on our Win7 64bit systems (in compatibility mode).

Then along comes the need to make some changes to the DLL files.   Fine, no problem.  We have the code.   But we don't have the code for the user interface program.  So in order to continue to use the same user interface program, I need my exports to EXACTLY match the names that were exported in the old DLLs.

But the old DLLs were written in 1998 on a Borland compiler.  And I'm using Visual Studio.

I need to be able to FORCE the linker to use a particular name verbatim.

For example, the function SysReg::TandemUnlock(DWORD) was originally exported decorated as @SysReg@TandemUnlock$quil.

I need to be able to match that.    I though I could do it with a DEF file.

I have tried DEF file that has

EXPORTS

@SysReg@TandemUnlock$quil

did not work.

I have also tried linker option /EXPORT:@SysReg@TandemUnlock$quil=SysReg::TandemUnlock

also did not work

Any ideas how to force this?
Do I have no option but to build the DLL first and then edit the PE?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Got the answer:  in the DEF file under the exports section I put @SysReg@TandemUnlock$quil=?SysReg@TandemUnlock@@YAKK@Z  of which the right hand side is the default decoration (what you get if you just do __declspec(dllexport) )

Comment: i have the same problem but no luck... 
in my def : 
EXPORTS
_ap_abort_on_oom@0=__E__0__ @1 
but after build the function is "_ap_abort_on_oom" and i need the @0 can you post more details?